# python - parse a bot true a list of bots ( bot_list )

Tags: python, apache, logparser

We have a apache_log parser. We tried several whay to parse the bot true a list of bots ( bot_list ). But without success. We tried comparing two lists, but the bot comes or is not a list.

What we want to achieve is that the bot first goes through a bot_list. So that only the bots coming through that are not in the bot_list.

```
log = apache_log(lines)

for r in log: 
    bot = r['bot']



bot_list = [ "Googlebot/2.1", 
             "AhrefsBot/5.0", 
             "bingbot/2.0", 
             "DotBot/1.1", 
             "MJ12bot/v1.4.5", 
             "SearchmetricsBot", 
             "YandexBot/3.0", 
             ]
```

It is working for one bot on this way.

```
bot = r['bot'].strip()
if not bot.startswith("Googlebot/2.1"):
```

This is so to say our filter, bot.startwith. 
But how can we achieve that the goes first through the bot_list?

Hope someone can bring us in the right direction?

Comment: You can pass a tuple of prefixes to [`str.startswith`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith).

Comment: Ashwini Chaudhary - thank that helped us to understand the way we can use the startswith. We got that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem, you may want to check if bot is not in the bot_list. I would suggest to get the bot name from the logfile:

```
bot_name = r["bot"].split(" ")[22]
if bot_name not in bot_list:
```

Let 22 be the position of the UserAgent in your logfile, [which you might have already customized](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#logformat).

If the position is not clear you can use a function:

```
if not len(filter(lambda x: x in r["bot"], bot_list)):
```

Which is the same as

```
return_list = []
for i in bot_list:
    if i in r["bot"]:
        return_list.append(i)
return len(return_list)
```

Comment: TuTTe - Thanks, bot_name = r["bot"] without the .spilt(" ")[8] did it. We were looking for something but could not come on this one "if bot_name not in bot_list:" so thanks this works for us.